# Different web paths, different Symfony2 apps

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony, virtualhost

I have have a Symfony2 based app it resides in web/app.php.

In same project I have a different app - web/app_api.php, which basically expose API to public.

I need to modify .htaccess file (or Apache config) so all requests to url /api/* would use app_api.php and all others app.php. How can that be done?

Edit.

Current .htaccess file:

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
# If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
# project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
# resolution of the app.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
# work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
# fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
# the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

# Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
# (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
# rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
# endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
# redirect -> request -> ...).
# So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
# to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
# environment variable, you have 2 choices:
# - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
# - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
#   following RewriteCond (best solution)
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

# If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
# We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]

# Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
    # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
    # and the generated links can still be used.
    RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `web` folder, try an `.htaccess` file with these lines:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^api /app_api.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(?!api) /app.php [L]
```

Comment: I've added current .htaccess file. Where should I add these lines?

Comment: I don't know what's in the current htaccess. If there are no other rewrites, you can add it at the bottom.